# Pass data through a segue via a button in a cell… Not working…

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

I've got a rather complicated cell in a custom UITableView. There's multiple elements in that cell, and I would like to be able to show a map controller when the user is clicking on a specific image.

I first tried to do that with a simple button and those functions :

```
import UIKit


class SousCategorieViewController: UITableViewController {

var rubSegue = NSDictionary()

@IBOutlet weak var bigLogoOutlet: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var titreOutlet: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var introOutlet: UILabel!    


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let bigLogo = rubSegue["gfx"]!["bigLogo"]!
    bigLogoOutlet.image = UIImage(named: "\(bigLogo!)")

    let titre = rubSegue["gfx"]!["titre"]!
    titreOutlet.text? = "\(titre!)".uppercaseString
    self.title = titre as? String
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 3000
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

}

 override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


// MARK: - Table View

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return rubSegue["corpus"]!.count

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let corpusArray = rubSegue.objectForKey("corpus") as! NSArray

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellChapter", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UniversalXIB

        cell.sousTitreOutlet.text = corpusArray[indexPath.row]["soustitre"] as? String
        cell.introOutlet.text = corpusArray[indexPath.row]["intro"] as? String
        cell.titreOutlet.text = corpusArray[indexPath.row]["titre"] as? String
        cell.imageOutlet.image = UIImage(named: (corpusArray[indexPath.row]["imageNP"] as! String))
        let texteArray = corpusArray[indexPath.row].objectForKey("texteArray") as? NSDictionary
        let iconesArray = corpusArray[indexPath.row].objectForKey("iconesArray") as? NSDictionary
        deleteStackOrNot((corpusArray[indexPath.row]["iconesNPBool"] as! Bool), stack: cell.iconesStackOutlet)
        deleteImagesOrNot((corpusArray[indexPath.row]["mapBool"] as! Bool), nameImage: (corpusArray[indexPath.row]["map"] as! String), stackRoot: cell.titreOutletStack, outlet: cell.mapOutlet)


        return cell
        }

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {


    if segue.identifier == "mapSegue" {
        if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? Map {
            if let rubIndex = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row {
                print(rubIndex)
                destination.nomVariable = rubIndex

            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

There's 3 cells and the only thing that is printed is :

```
0
0
```

No matter what the selected cell. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Provide more code of your view controller in your question

Comment: Et voilà, there you go !

Comment: Okay so your problem is that you alway get 0 as the rubIndex?

Comment: Yes ! But the idea behind that is to get the row number (which corresponds to an number in a plist), so if you have another idea…
edit : Ok I understand your question : I get 0 no matter the cell number.

Comment: Do you ever reloadRowsAtIndexPath? As that can reset the indexPathForSelectedRow

Comment: Nope… Ok I'm pasting more of my vc in the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, in that case you could add a tag to the button when you create it in cellForRowAtIndexPath of the current index:

```
button.tag = indexPath.row
```

Then in prepareForSegue grab the tag from the sender (the button) which will then be your selected cell index - rubIndex:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let button = sender as? UIButton {
        let rubIndex = button.tag
        print(rubIndex)
    }
}
```

Comment: Mpf :/ I'm so sorry to abuse of your kindness but when I copy/paste the prepareForSegue part, I get a 'let' declarations cannot be computed properties… Can you edit your post so it has the whole func prepareForSegue ? Soooooo sorry if its too much to ask !

Comment: Sorry missed off the 'if' bit before the 'let button' - updated the answer. I don't have Xcode so this is manually typed

Comment: Haha ok didn't know you could do that ! Good to know.

Answer (score 1):

try and change your prepareforsegue to the following:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "mapSegue" {
        if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? Map, button = sender as? UIButton, rubIndex = tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(button.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: tableView)) {
                print(rubIndex.row)
                destination.nomVariable = rubIndex.row
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mmm I get this :
    Could not cast value of type 'UIButton' (0x107ce9bf8) to 'UITableViewCell' (0x107ce9540).

Comment: Oh wait, so you never actually select on a cell?...its a button

Comment: Yes ! Sorry, I thought I was clear… That's what I meant when I said "I first tried to do that with a simple button and those functions", I've put a button in the cell and ctrl+drop it on the new vc, and then, identify the segue as mapSegue